# SQL query that will add a column returning a value when two other columns match (similar to vlookup in excel)

Tags: sql, addition

I have an employee table that lists all employees and the ID of their manager. The Manager ID refers back to the employee id in this table. I would like to add another column that returns the name of the manager since no one knows their ID numbers.

Current table is basically:
ID   Name          ManagerID
31    John Smith    10
32     Barb Jones   10
33    Craig Adams  32

I would like to add another column that looks up looks up the manager ID in the ID field and returns the assocaited name like below:

ID   Name         ManagerID   ManagerName
31   John Smith    10                   Ted Fish
32   Barb Jones    10                   Ted Fish
33   Craig Adams  32                  Barb Jones

Comment: You want a JOIN. Try posting your current SELECT code. You should have a table with the managers and their names; join the employee table with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use self-join here.

```
select e.ID, e.Name, m.ManagerID, e.Name as ManagerName
  from employee e
 inner join employee m
    on e.ID = m.ManagerID;
```